# Define region in region with same end match

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Let's see an example:

```
block
    property Property1
        key: value
    end
    property Property2
        key: value
    end
end
```

I would like to let property/end pair highlight only in block/end region, and key:value highlight only in property/end region. In this case how do I define the end of the region?